# Determining the functional length of a pattern in a "Like" comparison

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to determine the functional length of a pattern in a "Like" comparison?

For example, "[A-Z]" has a functional length of 1, but Len("[A-Z]") gives the answer 5 (because the string itself is five characters long).

I think being able to determine the functional length of the pattern would enable a more flexible way of looking through the string.

I have working code but it relies on the string being searched having spaces, and the substring to be found having a space on either side.

This is the code I tried; it doesn't work, because len(pattern) is longer than the pattern I'm trying to find - in my specific example the pattern is `#####[A-Z][A-Z]`, to find (for example) `11111AA` or `22222BB` - five numbers followed by two upper case letters.

```
Function ExtractMatch(Source As String, Pattern As String) As String
' extracts a substring matching the given pattern

    Dim i As Long, lenP As Long, Test As String
    lenP = Len(Pattern)
        For i = 1 To Len(Source) - lenP
            Test = Mid(Source, i, lenP)
            Debug.Print Test
            If Test Like Pattern Then
            ExtractMatch = Test
        Exit For
    End If
    Next
    
End Function
```

For context I am trying to extract a quote number from somewhere in a hand-typed entry. Sample data and desired output - line 5 is currently not captured as there's a typo, and no space before the quote number.

[Sample input/output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMpnz.png)

Comment: Is this particular pattern always between spaces? If so, you could also just split input and test each element. Other option would be to use a regular expression. Something like `\b\d{5}[A-Z]{2}\b`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Can you give a set of example data along with what your desired output is?

Comment: In my current application the pattern should be and almost always is between spaces; where it isn't it can be manually corrected, so my current solution does involve splitting the input. I'm looking at whether I can expand the flexibility to still extract the answer when it isn't delimited. I'll look at the regular expression thing - I've heard of them but never used them.

Comment: So, your answer is something like "the pattern may be or NOT between spaces". Would such an understanding be correct? If so, the first comment suggestion should be adapted eliminating its "\b" from extremities ("\d{5}[A-Z]{2}"). There are here many examples of `RegEx` using. Late or Early binding...

Comment: @AndiAllan This is a [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You ask about "determining the functional length of a pattern" but your actual problem is something completely different. You should ask about your original problem "How to extract the pattern matching substring".

Comment: I am trying to solve a more general problem; I have provided one example of its potential use. I also thought that understanding this one part of it was more grown-up than just asking other people to solve the entire problem for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that there are no `*` in the pattern we can get the length of the pattern using this function:

```
Function getPatterLength(ByVal Pattern As String) As Long
    If InStr(Pattern, "*") > 0 Then
        getPatterLength = -1
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim Parts() As String
    Parts = Split(Pattern, "[")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(Parts)
        If InStr(Parts(i), "]") > 0 Then
            Parts(i) = Mid(Parts(i), InStr(Parts(i), "]"))
        End If
    Next

    getPatterLength = Len(Join(Parts, ""))
End Function
```

It would be easier to add a parameter to the extract function for the pattern length.

```
Function ExtractMatch(Source As String, Pattern As String, PatterLength as long) As String
' extracts a substring matching the given pattern

    Dim i As Long, Test As String
        For i = 1 To Len(Source) - PatterLength
            Test = Mid(Source, i, PatterLength)
            Debug.Print Test
            If Test Like Pattern Then
            ExtractMatch = Test
            Exit Function
        End If

        Exit For
    End If
    Next
    
End Function
```

Comment: Your second bit is particularly clever - when entering the pattern, you'd know how long it is functionally, so why bother working it out in code! Brilliant - thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Thought it would be fun (for some at least) to see if this can be done through `FILTERXML()`:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=MAP(A2:A5,LAMBDA(x,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,MID(x,SEQUENCE(LEN(x)),7))&"</s></t>","//s[string-length(normalize-space())=7][substring(.,1,5)*0=0][translate(substring(.,6),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','')=''][1]")))
```

The deconstructed xpath *anding* predicates:

- `[string-length(normalize-space())=7]` - We need to test if the node's length equals 7 characters (after normalization: This is important due to the working of the 3rd predicate). In regex terms: `^.{7}$`;
- `[substring(.,1,5)*0=0]` - Test that the first 5 characters of the node are numeric. In regex terms: `^\d{5}`;
- `[translate(substring(.,6),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','')='']` - Assert that the last two characters are uppercase alpha chars. In regex terms: `[A-Z]{2}$`;
- `[1]` - Retrieve the 1st node from resulting filtered node-list.

Comment: This looks jolly clever - I'll try it out and go over your notes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regular Expressions to extract a submatch like below:

```
Public Sub Example()
    Debug.Print ExtractSubstring("Quote number 11111AA refers", "[0-9]{5}[A-Z]{2}")
End Sub

Public Function ExtractSubstring(ByVal InputString As String, ByVal Pattern As String) As String
    Dim RetVal As String
    Dim AllMatches As Object
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    
    With RegEx
        .Pattern = Pattern
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True  ' change this if you want case sensitivity
    End With
    Set AllMatches = RegEx.Execute(InputString)
    
    If AllMatches.Count <> 0 Then
        RetVal = AllMatches.Item(0)
    End If
    
    ExtractSubstring = RetVal
End Function
```

Or even use it directly like a UDF (User Defined Function)

```
=ExtractSubstring(A2,"[0-9]{5}[A-Z]{2}")
```

[image]

Note this will only return the first match if there are more matches with this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use regular expressions:

```vb
Public Sub test()

Dim pattern As String
pattern = "\d{5}[A-Z]{2}"

Debug.Print regex_PatternMatch(pattern, "11111AA")  'will return true
Debug.Print regex_PatternMatch(pattern, "111AA")   'will return false

End Sub

Public Function regex_PatternMatch(pattern As String, textToCheck As String) As Boolean
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    With regEx
        .pattern = pattern
        regex_PatternMatch = .test(textToCheck)
    End With
End Function
```

You have to add a reference to VB Script regular expressions

[image]

Comment: Thanks - the simple answer is that I don't know them well enough to use them. I will rectify that.